# itext DataMatrix barcode with UTF-8 chars

Tags: c#, utf-8, itext, datamatrix

What properties need to be set on an itextsharp Data-Matrix barcode to enable me to pass UTF-8 chars into the content?

```
var matrix = new BarcodeDatamatrix();
iTextSharp.text.Image img = null;

//matrix.Options = BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_ASCII;
matrix.Options = BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_AUTO;
//matrix.Options = BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_B256;
//matrix.Options = BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_TEXT;

matrix.Generate("!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;< => ?@[\\]^_`{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬ ®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ");

img = matrix.CreateImage();
```

This c# code creates the barcode, but the contents are invalid. I've tried the other listed `matrix.Options` too.

Comment: Can you share the barcode image that is produced? I generated a barcode in Java without any options and it does produce correct result (according to [this](https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/) online barcode reader)

Comment: I'm using iTextSharp to create the barcode, and I believe that this is where the problem lies.

Comment: I tried with iTextSharp and got the same correct result, so I believe the problem is not in the software.

Comment: @AlexeySubach the problem was with the scanner I was using, not the code. Changed to a different scanner and all seems fine! FYI I'm using a barcode scanner on Android. "Barcode Scanner v4.3" works OK, but "QR Scanner v0.33" did not. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look how simple it was! You could just use the link I gave you in the first place and save yourself a day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the scanner I was using and not the code.

@AlexeySubach posted an example of an online scanner that works. I was using a scanner on Android that did not work.

In the end I have switched apps to [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en_GB&rdid=com.google.zxing.client.android) by Zxing and this is now working well.

(I have no affiliation to this app nor the developers)